# How to filter results with sed using today's date

Tags: date, sed, debian, sh

I'm asking because I can't find how to correctly use the `sed` function with the `date` function.

**Context**: I am concatenating log files into one with the `cat` function. So far so good.
The date formats in the concatenated file might be: Feb 6, or 2022-02-07.
I would like with the `sed -i` function to keep only the lines of the current date.
I tried using the `date` function in the `sed` function:

- `sed -i '/^$(date +%b)d/;/$(date +%d)/d' XYZ.log`
- `sed -i '/"$(date +%b)"/ from XYZ.log`

I tried to use a variable in the `sed` function:

- `MONTH=$(date '+%b')`
- `sed -i '/^"$MONTH"/ !d' XYZ.log`

Both don't work.

**Request**: How to use the `date` function with the `sed` function in order to have in the XYZ.log file only the logs of the day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *sed* command is used to change text input; if you want to filter text you typically use the *grep* command, for instance like this:

```
grep "^$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" XYZ.log
```

Comment: Hello.

Thank you for your reply.
I have to use `sed` and not `grep` since the log file is then used by `ccze` to edit the logs in html format.

I used your command to successfully edit my `sed` command.

However, I have a new question.
In another log file the date format is 02/15/2022. My problem now is that sed interprets the "/" in the date command (`date +%m/%d-%Y`).

Do you know how to make sed not interpret the "/"?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @ephedan You can use basically any character as separator in sed, e.g. a bar ("|") instead of a slash.